# Jmeter Regex http response

Tags: regex, jmeter

I am trying to "catch" a  value from a json response using regex.

The response:

```
{"Result":0,"ResponseStatus":{"ErrorCode":null,"Message":null,"StackTrace":null,"Errors":null},"SessionId":"5a004b3b-f610-4a4e-9a0c-9953cee9bd47","ResponseHeader":{"Succeeded":true,"Errors":[]}}
```

I have created a HTTP request and added a child "JSON PATH EXTRACTOR" with the following data:

Destination Variable Name: SessionId_Regex

JsonPath Expression: "SessionId":"(.{8}-.{4}-.{4}-.{4}-.{12})"

The question is: how do i use the variable of the regex in a 2nd HTTP request

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you want to get the value of SessionId ? why don't your use json parser

Comment: I also tried it, i dont understand where i put the variable  regex name in the 2nd http request

Comment: Did you want to get the value of SessionId using this ```(.{8}-.{4}-.{4}-.{4}-.{12})``` ?

Comment: Use a `JSON` parser instead! If you insist, try this regex: [`"SessionId":"([^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/xP1uA0/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Path has nothing in common with Regular Expressions, you won't extract the value using above expression.

Change it to: `$..SessionId[0]`

You can refer extracted value directly as `${SessionId_Regex}` or using [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) function like `${__V(SessionId_Regex)}`  where required

References:

- [JSONPath - XPath for JSON](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/)
- [Using the XPath Extractor in JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) (scroll down to **Parsing JSON**)